# Installing Packages fail - R, Windows 10 pro

Tags: r

I have installed R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair" and R studio (Version 0.99.903 ) on windows 10 pro and I cannot install packages even when I run R and/or R studio under Run as administrator.
The question I get is: Would you like to use a personal library instead? Which if I say yes it doesn’t allow me to access the package later.

Any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: Install R directly under C:\ not C:\Program Files. That helped in my case.

Comment: Installed in C:\R and it did not work. The error "Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mino/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "C:/Users/Mino/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"' is not writable"

Comment: What is `.libPaths()`?

Comment: [1] "C:/Users/Mino/Documents/R/win-library/3.3" "C:/R/R-3.3.1/library"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `.libPaths() <- "C:/R/R-3.3.1/library"`. Afterwards you should only see this one and installation there should be fine. If you can't write to the folder, check if you have the correct rights.

Comment: I get this error.   > .libPaths() <- "C:/R/R-3.3.1/library"
Error in .libPaths() <- "C:/R/R-3.3.1/library" : 
  invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

Comment: Like that: `.libPaths(.libPaths()[2])`. If that does not work: `.libPaths("C:/R/R-3.3.1/library")`. Quite some time ago I had that problem...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked but I notice that every time I need to install a package I will have to change it. Any permanent solution?

Comment: To my knowledge no, but if you rember this post, it is done in a second;-) If it helped, please upvote the answer and mark it as solved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue right now. And this questioncomes up as the first hit on Google. Unforunately, the other answer kept giving me the errors that are mentioned in the comments section.

Then the following worked for me:

Navigate into: `C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3` where R is installed by default.

It would look like something below.

[image: R installation folder]

Right-click on the library folder and choose `Properties`, which would open the following dialog.

[image: Properties]

Click `Edit...` which would open the following dialog:

[image: Edit]

and scroll under `Group or user names` down to `Users (<foo-bar>\Users` and click it.

And check under `Permissions for Users` to `Full control`.

Click `Apply` and `OK`.

Now you can install libraries under the default library path.